# expect syntax problems

Tags: python, expect

I'm working on a script to automatically install phoronix test suite. The actual install goes smoothly, but the program requires php. It will be run on either RHEL or SUSE, meaning I have to have a case for each one (one for yum and the other for zypper). My problem comes in with using [expect](/questions/tagged/expect)- I can't get it to properly interact with the respective installers. Does anyone have pointers for what I'm doing incorrectly, syntax-wise or other? Much appreciated.

Side note-if there's a way to do this with [python](/questions/tagged/python), that would be amazing to hear about.

```
spawn ./wgetphoronix.py
expect {"Phoronix install finished. RHEL OS." {spawn yum install php \
                                        expect "Nothing to do." {break}\
                                                "Is this ok \\\[y/N\\\]: " {interact}}\
                                        {spawn yum install php-dom \
                                        expect "Nothing to do." {break}\
                                                "Is this ok \\\[y/N\\\]: " {interact}}}
        "Phoronix install finished. RHEL OS." {spawn zypper install php \
                                        expect "Nothing to do." {break}\
                                                "Is this ok \\\[y/N\\\]: " {interact}}\
                                        {spawn zypper install php-dom \
                                        expect "Nothing to do." {break}\
                                                "Is this ok \\\[y/N\\\]: " {interact}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PExpect is pretty nice](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect), you should probably check it out.

Also, look into autoexpect if you need to do it in expect.

Comment: I do have to do it in expect; it's for servers I can't assume much about. Sadly, autoexpect seems to be nonfunctional when it comes to yum. Do you have any other advice?